# Return array from function.

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to return an array from this function. This is the function:

```
   public static string[] loadServers() {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                string getString = client.DownloadString("http://flippr.pw/en/web_service/servers.json");
                client.Dispose();
                Dictionary<string, Servers> listOfServers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Servers>>(getString);
                return listOfServers;
            }
```

How can I return the array to a declared array?

Comment: `listOfServers` is a `Dictionary`, not an array. What exactly had you wanted?

Comment: use linq ToArray() for the keys or the relevant prop on the Servers object.

Comment: are you just wanting the `string` keys? `return listOfServers.Keys.ToArray()`

Comment: So what should be in string array??

Comment: @JonB I want to return the array from that function to my declared statement `public static string[] servers;`

Comment: @user3334215 there is no array, there is a Dictionary. A dictionary contains key-value pairs. What data are you trying to return as an array?

Comment: sure.  In the future, try to give as much information as you can when asking a question to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to return an array of strings then the following sample shows one method:

```
Dictionary<string, int> listOfServers = new Dictionary<string, int>();
listOfServers.Add("Server 1", 123980123);
listOfServers.Add("Server 2", 123234235);
string[] results = listOfServers.Select (x => x.Key).ToArray();
```

where the int part of the listIfServers stands for the `Servers` type. For you example above it would be simply

```
return listOfServers.Select (x => x.Key).ToArray();
```

Otherwise change the signature of your method to the `Dictionary<string, Servers>` return type.

Answer (score -4):

your return type is Dictionary and in you function you specified return type as string[].

```
 public static Dictionary<string, Servers> loadServers() {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                string getString = client.DownloadString("http://flippr.pw/en/web_service/servers.json");
                client.Dispose();
                Dictionary<string, Servers> listOfServers =                        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Servers>>(getString);
                return listOfServers;
            }
```

Comment: `I am trying to return an array from this function` - you're not returning an array. The question is unclear, so there is no clear answer.

Comment: Actually, *return type* is `Array` and OP trying to return dictionary

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. -1